# Java variable defined inside a loop doesn't seem to be recognized outside the loop?

Tags: java, variables, loops

I have a section of code that is puzzling me. I define an integer array inside an if/else statement because the length of the array depends on the length of 2 inputs to the method. My problem is that outside the if/else statement, the variable definition seems to be lost.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

  public String AddArrays(int [] arg1, int [] arg2) {
    int L1 = arg1.length;
    int L2 = arg2.length;
    if (L1 > L2) {
        int[] output = new int[L2];
        for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
            output[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
        }
    } else {
        int[] output = new int[L1];
        for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
            output[i] = arg1[i] + arg1[i];
        }
    }
    String result = Arrays.toString(output);
    return result;
    }
}
```

The error I get is on the statement `String result = Arrays.toString(output);` where Eclipse tells me that `output` cannot be resolved to a variable.

...and by the way, yes, I know that this is not the way to add two integer arrays -- I reduced this from more complex code to demonstrate the problem!

Comment: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: I agree. Working as designed. Not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `output` before `if` statement. Like this:

```
int[] output;
int L1 = arg1.length;
int L2 = arg2.length;
if (L1 > L2) {
    output = new int[L2];
    for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
        output[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
    }
} else {
    output = new int[L1];
    for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
        output[i] = arg1[i] + arg1[i];
    }
}
String result = Arrays.toString(output);
return result;
}
```

When you declared `output` inside the `if` statement it simply had only that block scope.

Comment: But the length of `output` depends on the if/then result. If arg1 is the larger then the length should be L2, or if arg2 is larger, then the length should be L1. Or is there a different approach I should use? Thanks.

Comment: But you don't create object yet. You simply declare that `output` will be an array. In this way you say 'hey, I know that I will use int array `output` but I don't know how to initialize it yet, but stay cool. I will initialize it a few instructions later."

Answer (score 3):

Scope of a variable is always the next enclosing `{` `}`.

Of cause starting at its declaration (not at the `{`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have already got the solution, but I would like to point out that, you can reduce your methods, to avoid duplicating codes, which you are currently doing.

You can make use of `conditional operators` to create the array according to the result of `L1 > L2`. And rather than iterating till `L1` or `L2`, you should iterate till the length of array `output`.

So, you can try using the below code: -

```
public String addArrays(int [] arg1, int [] arg2) {
    int L1 = arg1.length;
    int L2 = arg2.length;

    int[] output = L1 > L2 ? new int[L2]: new int[L1];

    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
    }

    return Arrays.toString(output);
}
```

And please follow Java Naming Conventions. Method name should start with lowercase alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the output variable as a local variable inside each of the if/else statements.  To fix this, declare it first outside then adjust it and return the results.  This keeps it in the scope between the brackets `{ }`.

```
public String AddArrays(int [] arg1, int [] arg2) {
    int L1 = arg1.length;
    int L2 = arg2.length;
    int[] output;
    if (L1 > L2) {
        output = new int[L2];
        for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
            output[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
        }
    } else {
        output = new int[L1];
        for (int i = 0; i < L2; i++) {
            output[i] = arg1[i] + arg1[i];
        }
    }
    String result = Arrays.toString(output);
    return result;
}
```